# Full screen responsive triangle pattern

Tags: jquery, html, css, canvas

Recently I dug a bit more into mobile UX design and I found a interesting topic regarding 1 hand / thumb selection.

The main idea is that you have 2 triangle areas that are clickable with your thumb. I did try to find a solution via CSS or jQuery to create 2 triangle areas that are click/touch-able with but I failed.

I tried:
- icon fonts
- svgs (this did not work, since svgs are still rectangular) 
- divs with borders shaped into a triangle
- canvas (did not work out so well)
- ASCII fonts
- jQuery, nothing really useful on this front :/
- rotated divs (CSS transform)

Do you have any suggestion about how I can achieve 2 responsive triangles that fit the screen, do not overlap as in this screen, that are clickable and accessible in the DOM?

The main point in terms of UI is that the users need so see the click / touchable areas (visually) in order to determine the possibility of interaction. Getting the area of a click (in a triangle style) is most likely not the problem. However, showing the users that they need to interact on a certain area is key.

I do not want to have scaled or different versions of pictures! Id like to see CSS or JavaScript solution...

I guess the biggest problem is that the triangle is not proportional + the responsiveness

This picture should illustrate the idea:
[image: responsive triangle]

Answer (score 8):

Your best bet may be to use a simple SVG

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <polyline points="0,0  1,0  0,1" fill="#F00" id="top"/>
    <polyline points="1,0  1,1  0,1" fill="#0F0" id="bottom"/>
</svg>
```

You can use CSS to style the elements on hover:

```
#top:hover {
    fill: #880000;
}
```

And jQuery to detect if an element has been clicked:

```
$('#top').click(function () { ...
```

Here's a demo: http://codepen.io/Godwin/pen/mIqlA

Answer (score 0):

Going outside the box a little bit - why not capture all click events, then mine out the x,y coordinates and do some simple math to determine which "triangle" the click occurred within?

If you need an actual triangle, then you could add in an svg or some other graphic, but don't base your UI on that actual graphic - base it on the location of the click?

If your layout/UI needs triangles that is a different question than detection. You could enforce the "triangle" layout with media queries and complicated breakpoints. However, your question didn't contain much in the way of specifics to guide an answer to your UI woes.

Comment: i did edit the post to explain the UI woes a bit more, thanks for your suggestions!