# How do I create a triangular responsive background image?

Tags: css, image, svg, background-image

I would like to have two images as a background that are diagonally separated. I think the best bet is by using SVG shapes as clipping masks, but I'm not sure.

The below image shows what I would like to achieve. As you can see those two images are perfectly diagonally split.

[image]

The issue that's been troubling me is that I cannot find a way to create such split while not stretching these images and keep it full screen at all time (thus responsive).

My question/goal:
How do I make a page that consists of two diagonally separated images that, together, make a fullscreen view of which the images are not stretched and the split is at both corners.

---

Edit: With help of [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21741066/full-screen-responsive-triangle-pattern) you can easily create the two diagonals. It's a matter of having images as backgrounds of those polygons. However, the images should be fullscreen and therefor should scale, instead of stretch.

*Copied the answer below*

```
Your best bet may be to use a simple SVG

<svg viewBox="0 0 25 25" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <polyline points="0,0  25,0  0,25" fill="#FF0000" id="top"/>
    <polyline points="25,0  25,25  0,25" fill="#00FF00" id="bottom"/>
</svg>
You can use CSS to style the elements on hover:

#top:hover {
    fill: #880000;
}

Demo here: http://codepen.io/Godwin/pen/mIqlA
```

Comment: maybe this other answer will help...seems similar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14889564/1028949

Comment: @Quantastical Hi! Thanks for your input. As I yet haven't found a full screen responsive way my idea was to create exactly as the answer you linked to. However, full screen and responsive is my final goal, so It's not a (great) answer yet. Still thanks, it will be helpful for sure!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `clip-path`

**Result** - https://jsfiddle.net/11kn8mjn/4/

**How It's Done**

Two fullscreen divs with responsive background images are positioned on top of each other.

Clip mask is used to show a responsive triangle of each div.

**Code**

Two divs positioned on top of each other:

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

With a responsive background image:

```
.div-one { background: url('http://i.imgur.com/8LgIL7B.jpg') center / cover no-repeat; }

.div-two { background: url('http://i.imgur.com/fBL4WC1.jpg') center / cover no-repeat; }
```

Clip path shows a triangle of each div. The triangle is made responsive using vh and vw values:

```
.div-one { clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100vh 0, 100vw 0); }

.div-two { clip-path: polygon(100vw 0, 0% 100vh, 100vw 100vh); }
```

**Browser Support**

Support for clip-path isn't great - http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path

Comment: Because of lack of browser support (IE) i've chosen to go with the suggestion from @Quantastical in the comments. However, you've provided what I asked for. Thank you incredibly!